# Why does Get-PSDrive return the DisplayRoot Property in the Root Property column?

Tags: powershell

If I use:

```
Get-PSDrive K
```

I get some properties returned, amongst others the Root property, which looks like this:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-psdrive K

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                    
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----        
K                                      FileSystem    \\server\share
```

but if I select Root, I get this returned:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-psdrive K | select Root

Root
----
K:\
```

DisplayRoot returns the root as seen in my first command:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-psdrive K | select DisplayRoot

DisplayRoot
-----------
\\server\share
```

`Format-List` also returns them like my two commands above

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-psdrive K | fl *


Used            : 0
Free            :
CurrentLocation :
Name            : K
Provider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
Root            : K:\
Description     :
MaximumSize     :
Credential      : System.Management.Automation.PSCredential
DisplayRoot     : \\server\share
```

I can just use DisplayRoot to get the UNC-Share, but why does `Get-PSDrive` on it's own return the DisplayRoot Property in the Root column? Is this by design?

I'm on:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
5.1.14393.2189
```

Comment: Looks like the column heading is displayed incorrectly. Happens for me too (5.1.17134.228). Found some others who have reported the same observation [link1](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3c8803c3-12d9-4ccb-8349-4505f6f4fdca/whats-up-with-getpsdrive-driveletter-select-root?forum=ITCG) [link2](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/3kxnz1/inconsistentancy_with_getpsdrive/)

Comment: That is because PowerShell have formatting system, which allows you to customize how objects should be displayed.